# Another metatag to remove [toggle]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Trogdor?
Please burninate the tag [toggle](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/toggle).

[image]

Comment: It's easier to just manually remove the tags from the 7 questions.

Comment: +1 solely for the Trogdor Signal

Comment: And for me having to explain to my little brother what a ["Trogdor"](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail58.html) was.